# How is i3 window manager started by startx in Ubuntu (so that I can configure what display it appears on)?

Tags: x11, i3, exec, startx, xinit

I want to set up i3 automatically start on a specific one of my three screens (all connected to one Nvidia card). This has proved more difficult than expected.

- My first choice was to just set that specific screen (HDMI) to be the main screen via GRUB options. However, it seems that is not possible with proprietary Nvidia drivers, which I need to use. So I gave up on that and only included it here as background.
  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-i-choose-which-monitor-is-primary-as-in-gets-the-tty-login-for-gt710/197021
- My second choice is to just `startx` automatically at boot and have it start i3 on the screen of my choice. I have already configured X screens so that I can address my displays like `:0.0`, `0.1`, `0.2`.
- At first I tried to get i3 on the display of my choice by `DISPLAY=:0.2 startx`, but obviously that doesn't work because the displays have not yet been assigned as `X` has not yet started.
- I thought I would try specifying the display by modifying the script that invokes `i3`, which I expected to be `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`. However I see nothing about i3 there, or in any of the other places I expected to find it such as `/etc/profile` or `/etc/X11/Xsession`. Grepping inside `/etc/X11` and my home folder for `exec i3` yielded nothing. So where is i3 actually being invoked when I run `startx`?
- Next, I tried `DISPLAY=:0.2 sudo xinit i3`. That opens up i3 on the main display, but with with an xterm window for the i3 process. If I quit this window, i3 closes. So this it wastes screen space on a window that I won't interact with.

## So my questions are:

1. How do I start `i3` with a command and have it open with the same result as when I run `startx`?
2. Where can I find the command which `startx` uses to invoke i3?

## Solution (but not answer)

I get the desired effect by creating ~/.xinitrc with `DISPLAY=0.2 exec i3`. However I am still curious how i3 was being invoked before. I would rather have made this change there. And why does i3 need to be started with `exec` instead of `xinit`?

Comment: X startup is very flexible, but this can make it complicated to figure out. Do you have a ~/.xsession file? Do you have a ~/.startxrc file? Start with the manual page for `startx` and look at the files it references. See if /usr/bin/x-session-manager exists and if so does it link to /etc/alternatives. Typically you have a `session manager` started by `startx` as the client and it will start your `window manager` (i3 in your case).

Comment: @icarus no, I have neither of them. That's what is bothering me. I cannot find the`exec i3` command in any of the usual suspects.

Comment: Perhaps `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is looking a var called `WINDOWMANAGER` which sets it, and it is being set via `/etc/profile.d/profile.sh`.